# Finding common subsequences in list of sequences

Tags: python-3.x

Python question here. I have a list of lists. Each list represents a sequence. Let's say for example I have:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 3], [1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]
```

What I am trying to find is the subsequences of arbitrary length, greater than some integer, that are common among the sequences (ordered). For example for length of 2, here we would have `[0, 1, 2]` repeated two times between `[0, 1, 2]` and `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. We would have `[1, 2]` be repeated two times between `[0, 1, 2]` and `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. We would have `[3, 2, 1]` repeated three times between the three lists `[3, 2, 1]`.

I tried the following but am getting back subsequences that are not contiguous and the counter also only goes up to 1:

```py
lines = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 3], [1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]

    for i in range(len(lines)):
        for j in range(len(lines)):
            if i!=j:
                intersection = set(lines[i]).intersection(set(lines[j]))
                if len(intersection) >= len_int:
                    counter[f'{intersection}'] =+1
```

```py
counter
{'{0, 1, 2}': 1, '{1, 2}': 1, '{0, 3}': 1, '{1, 2, 3}': 1}
```

So essentially, to summarize, I want the common subsequences in a list of sequences - using python. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: From a quick glance, it seems to come from the conversion of your list to a `set`, which is unordered and `set.intersection()` doesn't care for contiguous-ness. E.g. `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.intersection({1, 5, 10})` gives you `{1, 5}`

Comment: Yes, that's true, but still I'm looking for a solution to finding the subsequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick glance, it seems to come from the conversion of your list to a `set`, which is unordered and `set.intersection()` doesn't care for contiguous-ness. E.g. `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.intersection({1, 5, 10})` gives you `{1, 5}`

A way around this -- and this is probably not a very efficient one -- would be to find all the sub-sequences greater than the desired length in each list, and then keep track of the count in a dictionary.

First, let's define a function that'll get you the subsequences of a given length, by popping the first element from the previous sub-sequence and pushing the next element of the main sequence into the sub-sequence:

```
def get_subsequences(main_seq, length):
    """Returns the sub-sequences of the given length as tuples"""
    seq = main_seq[0:length]
    yield tuple(seq)
    index = length
    while index < len(main_seq):
        seq.pop(0)
        seq.append(main_seq[index])
        index += 1
        yield tuple(seq)
```

Let's test this:

```
>>> list(get_subsequences([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2))
  [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]

>>> list(get_subsequences([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3))
  [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```

Next, let's write a wrapper that will return all sub-sequences *greater than or equal to* the desired length:

```
def get_subsequences_gte(main_seq, min_length):
    """Returns all sub-sequences >= the given length"""
    current_length = min_length
    while current_length <= len(main_seq):
        subseqs = get_subsequences(main_seq, current_length)
        for ss in subseqs:
            yield ss
        current_length += 1
```

Let's test this:

```
>>> list(get_subsequences_gte([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3))
  [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
```

Finally, let's use this function and keep track of the count of each sub-sequence in a dictionary.

```
all_sequences = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 3], [1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]

min_length = 2

count_sequences = dict()
for sequence in all_sequences:
    for subseq in get_subsequences_gte(sequence, min_length):
        count_sequences[subseq] = count_sequences.get(subseq, 0) + 1

print(count_sequences)
```

Which gives us:

```
{
 (0, 1): 2,
 (1, 2): 3,
 (0, 1, 2): 2,
 (2, 3): 2,
 (1, 2, 3): 2,
 (0, 1, 2, 3): 1,
 (0, 3): 1,
 (0, 2): 1,
 (2, 1): 4,
 (0, 2, 1): 1,
 (3, 2): 3,
 (3, 2, 1): 3
}
```

As you expect, `(0, 1, 2)` repeats `2` times. `(3, 2, 1)` repeats `3` times. Your expectation for `(1, 2)` to be repeated two times is incorrect -- it is repeated in `[0, 1, 2]`, `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, and `[1, 2, 3]` (`3` times, as correctly calculated by this code)

---

To filter out sub-sequences that do not repeat, simply filter out the `count_sequences` dictionary after it has been populated.

```
count_common = {k: v for k, v in count_sequences.items() if v > 1}
```

which gives:

```
{
 (0, 1): 2,
 (1, 2): 3,
 (0, 1, 2): 2,
 (2, 3): 2,
 (1, 2, 3): 2,
 (2, 1): 4,
 (3, 2): 3,
 (3, 2, 1): 3
}
```